# Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string

Tags: php

I am getting output from my coding in my website as report.In my report when i search by passport/IC i can get the data But when i applied this code in google column chart its not working. its showing an error. 1st time i am using google column chart. I am not finding way to solve this error. Could anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

**HERE IS MY CODE**

```
<?php


        $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mypro_bms;host=localhost', 'root', '');
        $people = [];
        if (!empty($_GET['q'])) {
          $count='count';
          $sum='sum';
          $stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT passport_IC,sum(blood_bag) as sum FROM donate 
                where passport_IC like :passport_IC  GROUP BY passport_IC ");
           $stmt->execute([
            ':passport_IC' => '%' . $_GET['q'] .'%'
            ]);  
         $people = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
         ?> 
        <html>
          <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
              google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

              function drawChart() {

                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                  ['passport_IC', 'sum' ],

                ]);

                var options = {
                  title: 'Blood Volume Rate',
                  is3D: true,

                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

                chart.draw(data, options);
            }

            </script>
          </head>
          <center><body>
            <body>
          <div class="panel panel-default">

          <div class="container mt-5">
            <div class="card">
               <div class="card-header" style="background-color: none; border-radius: 5px">
                <center><h2><strong>All Donors Record</strong></h2></center>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
                    <form class="my-4">
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Passport/IC.....">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Check</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div><br>
            <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
            <?php foreach($people as $donors): ?>
                     <?= $donors->passport_IC; ?>
                       <?= $donors->sum; ?>
                      <?php endforeach; ?>
          </body></center>
        </html>
```

Comment: Can you please show us the error?

Comment: Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string.....This is the error